# Regression from image by CNN: output lies within a small range around the mean

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, conv-neural-network

I am very new to CNN, ML etc and stuck at a problem.

I have a regression problem. The problem is as follows.

I have many(5000) hermitian matrices which are converted to greyscale images(each pixel value is basically the matrix element, scaled to 0-255). Each image is of size 70X70. However, in the main problem all the individual image pixel values are normalized to 0-1.

Now, it is known that diagonalizing these matrices(X) and further doing some mathematics one can arrive at a number(y) unique to a particular matrix. The range of y is typically within the range 0.2-0.6.

I am trying to solve a regression problem using CNN followed by few deep layers on Tensorflow in which the input is X and target output is y. (It may be equivalent to the problem of age determination from facial image)

The problem is that the model always predicts y values close to the mean i.e. 0.4+-small fluctuations. Closer look reveals that the fluctuations do somewhat follow the trend of my target y values but the predicted values lie only within the range 0.35-0.45 approx.

I get an MSE~7×10^-4 at every fold of 5-fold cross validation.

What is/are the problems that I should look for? I am totally a beginner in this field. Any help or thoughts will be much appreciated. TIA.

```
fold_no = 1
for train, test in kfold.split(inputs, targets):

  
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(20, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(1))

  
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-01, decay=0.0)
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')


  
  print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')
  print(f'Training for fold {fold_no} ...')

  
  history = model.fit(inputs[train], targets[train],
              batch_size=batch_size,
              epochs=no_epochs,
              verbose=verbosity)
  
  
  scores = model.evaluate(inputs[test], targets[test], verbose=0)
  print(f'Score for fold {fold_no}: {model.metrics_names} of {scores}')
  
  loss_per_fold.append(scores)

  fold_no = fold_no + 1
```

Comment: please show relevant code. Without that can not help

Comment: @GerryP I have added the main body of my code. This is actually my first code, feel free to point out the mistakes and other improvements that I must do to make my model learn the data. Thank you :)